# IPC on Windows between Java and Python secured to the current user

Tags: java, python, windows, ipc, ssl-certificate

We have a Rest API that requires client certificate authentication.  The API is used by this collection of python scripts that a user can run.  To make it so that the user doesn't have to enter their password for their client certificate every time they run one of the scripts, we've created this broker process in java that a user can startup and run in the background which holds the user's certificate password in memory (we just have the javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword property set in the JVM). The scripts communicate with this process and the process just forwards the Rest API calls to the server (adding the certificate credentials).

To do the IPC between the scripts and the broker process we're just using a socket.  The problem is that the socket opens up a security risk in that someone could use the Rest API using another person's certificate by communicating through the broker process port on the other person's machine.  We've mitigated the risk somewhat by using java security to only allow connections to the port from localhost.  I think though someone in theory could still do it by remotely connecting to the machine and then using the port.   Is there a way to further limit the use of the port to the current windows user?  Or maybe is there another form of IPC I could use that can do authorization using the current windows user?

<strike>We're using Java for the broker process just because everyone on our team is much more familiar with Java than python but it could be rewritten in python if that would help.</strike>

**Edit:**  Just remembered the other reason for using java for the broker process is that we are stuck with using python v2.6 and at this version https with client certificates doesn't appear to be supported (at least not without using a 3rd party library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple approach is to use cookie-based access control. Have a file in the user's profile/homedirectory which contains the cookie. Have the Java server generate and save the cookie, and have the Python client scripts send the cookie as the first piece of data on any TCP connection.

This is secure as long as an adversary cannot get the cookie, which then should be protected by file system ACLs.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work.  I still have to use a separate java process to be the http client because we have to use python v2.6 and it doesn't appear to handle https with client certificates but, with using cookies I think I can just spawn a new java process everytime a python script runs and then just communicate with it using standard input/output

Comment: Python actually handles client certificates just fine, and had been doing so for quite some time.

Comment: Alright digging around in the documentation some more it does look like it can be done but, our certificates are in PKCS#12 format which doesn't appear to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a solution inspired by Martin's post above.  When the broker process starts up I'll create an mini http server listening on the IPC port.  Also during startup I'll write a file containing a randomly generated password (that's different every startup) to the user's home directory so that only the user can read the file (or an administrator but I don't think I need to worry about that). Then I'll lock down the IPC port by requiring all http requests sent there to use the password.  It's a bit Rube Goldberg-esque but I think it will work.